# What's the right way to convert an FSharpAsync object into a C# Task?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, f#

I'm trying to convert some F# code to C#. The C# code I'm writing depends on a Nuget package that I **cannot** change. One of the functions in the nuget package returns a type of FSharpAsync<FSharpChoice<Unit, CustomType>>.

I'd like to convert the FSharpAsync object to a C# task. I'm trying to use FSharpAsync.StartAsTask like so:

```
var task = FSharpAsync.StartAsTask<FSharpChoice<Unit, CustomType>>(fsharpAsyncObj, null, null);
```

Is this the appropriate way to do such a conversion? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use [Async.StartAsTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/async.startastask%5B't%5D-method-%5Bfsharp%5D) to make your API C#-friendly by converting the F#-specific Async type into a C# Task.